# Checking Parent Type TPT EF4

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, parent, table-per-type

I have a TPT scenario in EF4 with an abstract base class.

I need to wite a linq query against a collection of children types to get the value from a field of one type of parent.

eg.

```
ThisChild = Children.Where(c. => c.Parent.OfType<Mother>.JewelleryCollection > 10).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this case, Parent is the abstract class with Mother being a type of Parent. Mother is the only type that has a JewelleryCollection field.

The example above breaks because you cannot use the .OfType<> method. How can I best structure this query?

Thanks.

Comment: ObservableCollection<Child> Children = new ObservableCollection<Child>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are running the query on `ObservableCollection` it is Linq-to-objects where you can simply use conversion:

```
ThisChild = Children.FirstOrDefault(c => 
    (c.Parent is Mother) && (((Mother)c.Parent).JewelleryCollection > 10));
```